# Computer vision: How to follow a line while moving in (x,y) plane?

Tags: algorithm, computer-vision, line

In short what i want is to follow a line like the guy in this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iHiasfAE63k

In the comment section he said:

"I get the array of values from my ROI, one per degree. I then set a threshold level and turn these values into binary values. In my direction of travel I set a region (30 degrees) either side of that point and disregard anything outside of it. I find the centre value of the binary array representing line. This gives me an angle to drive to. I then turn this into a x and y velocity using sin cos functions. I feed the x any velocity into the stepper drives and the camera closes the loop."

And i didn't understand a thing from his explanation? can you guys shed some light on this algorithm?

Answer (score 0):

What I get from the info is that this guy is using a [binarization](http://felixniklas.com/imageprocessing/binarization) algorithm to only have an image with pure black and pure white, then you can represent each pixel using only a bit (0 for black, 1 for white; and sometimes in the most common way using a byte 0 for black, 255 for white). So you need to apply this algorithm first to generate an image to work with.

After that this guy chose a direction of travel and search for that pixels that are in this direction and belongs to a region of interest of +/- 15 grades of the traveling direction. He obtains the points that are in this direction and compute a value which tells him where to go and translates this value to the movement of the motors.